Pyspark - read csv and saving it to delta format folder errors out ( no pandas)
New to Pyspark and trying to play with parquet/delta ecosystem.
Trying to write a script that does the following

Read a csv file into a spark dataframe.
Save it as parquet file.
Read the above saved parquet file into a spark dataframe.
Save it as delta format file/folder.
Create a delta Table object from the above delta file.
Update/Append to the table

I am able to do till step 3 but step 4 errors out .
Script
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from delta import *
from delta.tables import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

from pyspark import SparkFiles
from pyspark.context import SparkContext

print("Kernel:", sys.executable)
print("Python version:", sys.version)
print("Spark version:", spark.version)
print("PySpark version:", pyspark.__version__)
print("PySpark Version :", spark.sparkContext.version)
    
spark = (
    SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]")
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.1.0")
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
    .getOrCreate()
)

csv_filename = "dataset/BankChurners.csv"

# read csv to spark dataframe
df_csv = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").load(csv_filename)

# save to parquet file
df_csv.write.parquet ("output/BankChurners_spark.parquet", mode="overwrite")

# read parquet file to spark dataframe
df_parq = spark.read.parquet("output/BankChurners_spark.parquet")

# save to delta format file
df_parq.write.format("delta").save("output/BankChurners_delta_table")

# read delta table
deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, "output/BankChurners_delta_table")

# add a record and save delta table
# did not find any example / syntax for adding a record

Output
Python version: 3.9.6 (default, Mar 29 2024, 10:51:09)
[Clang 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)]
Spark version: 3.5.1
PySpark version: 3.5.1
PySpark Version : 3.5.1
...
...
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/foobar/workspace/practice/parquet/question.py", line 31, in <module>
    df_parq.write.format("delta").save("output/BankChurners_delta_table")
  File "/Users/foobar/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 1463, in save
    self._jwrite.save(path)
  File "/Users/foobar/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "/Users/foobar/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py", line 179, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/Users/foobar/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o44.save.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/FileFormatWriter$Empty2Null

Questions:

how can I create the delta table?

For reading files (csv or parquet) , I noticed two different methods. Which one is preferred?
I.  df_csv = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").load(csv_filename)
II.  df_csv = spark.read.csv(csv_filename, header=True, inferSchema=True)

Is this the correct way to create object of an existing delta table ?
deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, "/path/to/table")

If yes to above, then how do I append a record to this data table so that it updates the table version ?

Are there modules that I need not import?


Feel free to comment on anything else you find incorrect.
Thanks



The mistake in the code is that when writing to Delta format, you are using saveAsTable, which creates a catalog table. Instead, you should use save to write directly to Delta files.


To append a DataFrame to Delta files, change the mode to append. Otherwise, you can update the Delta table by using the update method of the Delta table object.
I referenced it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/training/modules/use-delta-lake-azure-databricks/03-create-delta-tables




They are the same its just aliasing for ease of use
Yes given the correct path this API created a DeltaTable object
For appending new rows you should read a file to spark dataframe then user write() API to save the Dataframe into a delta location for ex:

# read csv to spark dataframe
df_csv = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").load(csv_filename)
# Append new rows from "CSV" into DeltaTable location
df_csv.write.mode("append").format("delta").save("path/to/delta/table")


@LuanNguyen- Thank you, after updating the script (also adding few print statement to get version numbers), I am getting a new error message. (updated in original post) . Google says that I should update my delta-core version.  but not sure if that is the correct . Also any idea what version it should be for spark 3.5.1 ?

@AmitShmulevitch- Thank you. maybe I did not communicate properly, what I am trying to understand is how can I read one record from delta table, update it and save it back (no csv involved) .
